# Patch argo-server authentication | kubectl gives "error: unknown flag: --auth-mode"

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, argo

I am trying to set Argo on my Windows laptop. I am following the docs: https://argo-workflows.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quick-start/

In the patch argo-server authentication, on running the command:

```bash
kubectl patch deployment \
  argo-server \
  --namespace argo \
  --type='json' \
  -p='[{"op": "replace", "path": "/spec/template/spec/containers/0/args", "value": [
  "server",
  "--auth-mode=server"
]}]'
```

I am getting the error:

```bash
error: unknown flag: --auth-mode
See 'kubectl patch --help' for usage.
```

How do I fix this? I am running on Windows.

Comment: Please update your question with more details on the error. I assume you're checking the logs? I suspect (!?) that the error results from incorrect use of `args`. See [Container](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.25/#container-v1-core). Kubernetes uses `command` for the container's `ENTRYPOINT` and `args` for the `CMD`. If the `argo-server` has an `ENTRYPOINT`, then you need only replace the flags with `args`. One way to validate this would be to know the value of `args` before the PATCH.

Comment: Try use it as one-liner `kubectl patch deployment argo-server --namespace argo --type=json -p="[{"op": "replace", "path": "/spec/template/spec/containers/0/args", "value": ["server","--auth-mode=server"]}]"` I tested it work on Windows (I did it in `cmd`)

Comment: I tried @zori 's  answer on cmd, it didin't work. But it worked on powershell.

Comment: Interesting, what is your windows version?

Comment: Windows 10 enterprise edition. Version 22H2